# Cannot describe in Snowflake. No active database

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

A newbie to Snowflake and I cannot use the database navigator to look at a table.

It gives me the following error: "Cannot perform DESCRIBE. This session does not have a current database. Call 'USE DATABASE', or use a qualified name."

I changed the context to use the right database.
I changed my role to SYSADMIN.
I entered "USE DATABASE CITIBIKE".

Still no joy.

Answer (score 2):

You can try specifying your database  while creating the connection with snowflake as below:

```
const connection = snowflake.createConnection({
    username: "username",
    password: "password",
    account : "accountname",
    database: "database name"
});
```

> Source :
> https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/nodejs-driver-use.html

Note : you can also specify schema, warehouse and role.
this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a worksheet or have you tried at the worksheet level with the necessary permissions to the object?  Perhaps try using the qualified name?  For example, if you're trying to describe a table in Snowflake: 
**desc table database_name.schema_name.table_name**

Please note if any of the objects here have special characters, were stored in lowercase, or have spaces, you may need to put double quotes around them.

**Edit:**  *After further investigation and understanding of the issue, this is actually a UI issue the Snowflake Dev team is working to resolve.  Hoping to see a fix in the next release.*

Comment: Thank you for helping out. I am trying to use the database navigator on the left side of the screen. Maybe I am using the wrong term for it but it is on the left side and you drill through the database to the table screen.

Comment: When I click on the table name I should get the table information. It looks for it. Gives me the error. And gives no results for column, etc.

Comment: The object browser (database navigator) is influenced by your worksheet context. You can change the context at the worksheet level and refresh the object browser.  This video should help with some of the basics:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mH4pvxcfNYw